# Distributed cache with overflow to disk

Tags: software-development

I am looking for a distributed cache solution (hosted by me).

Many items are a MB or so (e.g. generated images), which over the course of a week adds up to close to 100GB.

I do not have enough collective memory to support that simultaneously in-memory, so I need it to be able to overflow to disk (on a LRU basis).

Open source is preferred; commercial solutions acceptable.

Comment: Please do add some details on the environment you need this to run on. Operating System, Application Server (if any) etc.